# How to convert string of date without bars to date in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, date

I want to convert the next strings in date - AngularJS

```
var string1 = '20160801'; //yyyyMMdd

var string2 = '01082016'; //ddMMyyyy
```

What method could be used to receive any of the two parameters and make a date in this format "dd / MM / yyyy"?

Thank you

Comment: do you know which format the date will be in, or could it be in either format and you need some code to make an effort to guess which format the input is in? In the case of the latter, it's fairly easy as long as your dates can't be pre 14th century